# How to look for JUnit and TestNG tests with no assertions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

I've been able to figure out how to go about looking for tests that aren't run.  Does anyone know how I can go about figuring out if a test that was run doesn't have an assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two choices:  at runtime, or using static analysis.

**At runtime**

You will be able to hook into your tests at runtime using JUnit's [RunListener](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) (TestNG has a similar abstraction), but how could you tell when assertions are made?  Not straightforward, but this would be possible using a [Java Agent](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/javaagent-option.html).  You can use a java agent and a library which does bytecode manipulation to alter the behaviour of "assertion" methods as they are loaded into the JVM.  Your altered methods would have to call your RunListeners then make their assertions as ususal.  You need to be able to list every single method which counts as an "assertion" (junit?  testng?  hamcrest?, etc?).  Phew!  I have done all this in the past, it was pretty fiddly but it does work.

**Static analysis**

In your case, static analysis would seem to be the better choice.  You can scan the classpath for all @Test annotations (or TestNG equivalent) and check to see which of them call a method whose name starts "assert".  I've used [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) to do things similar to this and it works pretty well.

As mentioned in the other answer, be aware that there is always the implicit assertion that no exceptions are thrown.  We do have some valid and useful tests in our suites which have no explicit assertions in them because of this.

Comment: I already have something that reflects over the test code and figures out which are test methods (that's how I was able to figure out which tests aren't being run).

It looks like the output from "javap -c" can help figure out which tests have assertions, even the one's expecting an exception (the old way would have a call to 'Assert.fail' and possibly an assertion while the new way has a call to 'ExpectedException.expect').

This would work at least for the tests that have direct assertions, but not indirect assertions.  IMNSHO, assertions ought to be direct, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach could have been been JUnit and TestNG supporting assert counter which can print not just the number of tests but also asserts used in the test methods.

I have written a wrapper for Assert class which overrides all the methods and has a counter..

You could also try to use IntelliJ's Structured Search

Regards,
Nagendra

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet would be a regex search or some kind of static analysis. Whichever, it has to be able to identify test methods and determine whether they contain an assertion, where an assertion is some assert* call, a mock verification, and/or an "expected exception" clause at the very least. All of those constitute some kind of "assertion".

Comment: Of course, there's often an implicit assertion - assert(no exceptions thrown).